# Vanilo 3 error during configuration - Class App\Models\User must extend or implement Konekt\User\Contracts\User

Tags: php, laravel, vanilo

I followed the installation guide https://vanilo.io/docs/3.x/installation for vanilo step by step. Once all steps were completed, I tried to start up the development server with `php artisan serve`
and it threw an error:

> InvalidArgumentException
> Class App\Models\User must extend or implement Konekt\User\Contracts\User.

The default user model has been configured to extend the Konekt user model as described in the installation guide:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


class User extends \Konekt\User\Models\User
{
```

The boot method in AppServiceProvider contains:

```
$this->app->concord->registerModel(\Konekt\User\Contracts\User::class, \App\Models\User::class);
```

The error states that the user model needs to extend or implement a model from `Contacts\User`, and it does as declared in the `Konekt\User\Models`:

```
namespace Konekt\User\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Konekt\Enum\Eloquent\CastsEnums;
use Konekt\User\Contracts\Profile;
use Konekt\User\Contracts\User as UserContract;
use Konekt\User\Contracts\Profile as ProfileContract;
use Konekt\User\Events\UserWasActivated;
use Konekt\User\Events\UserWasCreated;
use Konekt\User\Events\UserWasDeleted;
use Konekt\User\Events\UserWasInactivated;

/**
 * User Entity class
 *
 */
class User extends Authenticatable implements UserContract
{
```

I've followed this installation guide twice over from scratch and it always leads to this error. I need help troubleshooting, as it appears everything is done properly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the namespace on the User model to default, despite the tutorial showing namespace App, I used namespace App\Models and that fixed it.

Comment: The tutorial can't precisely tell which version of Laravel you are using. Laravel - depending on which version you install - puts the default user model either in the `app/` or in the `app/Models` folder.